# truncate the double number and convert it to a string with the desired number of significant figures or decimal places

Tags: .net

I used C# to build a program in windows 7. I want to convert all decimals after decimal point to zero double type data .

For example, I want to achieve this function:

input21.123 output21.000

input15.8 output15.0

input178.51 output178.00

input3.4679 output3.0000

All the input data are double type.

The output will be written in the csv.

```
string data = '';
double WidthVal, LengthVal, AreaVal = 2.1, 3.45, 6.789;   

data += ',' + Math.Truncate(WidthVal);                          
data += ','  + Math.Truncate(LengthVal);
data += ','  + Math.Truncate(AreaVal);

using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(filename + ".csv"))
{
      sw.WriteLine(data);
      sw.Close();
}
```

desired output in csv: 2.0, 3.00, 6.000

Answer (score 0):

Following code can achieve what you want

```cs
string Y(double x)
{
    var s = x.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var i = s.IndexOf(".");
    return i == -1 ? s : Math.Truncate(x).ToString($"N{s.Length - 1 - i}");
}
```

Be aware though that e.g. `0.56` will be transformed to `"0.00"`. Also you may want to play a little bit more with output number format depending on your needs.